# Xcode Swift 3d Shortcuts Touch Navigation Bar not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, shortcut, 3dtouch

So I have just added 3d shortcuts to my app. Now they open the correct `ViewController` but I can't navigate through the rest of the app. It appears to open the `ViewController` as a `modal`. How to I get the navigation bar to show as well?

Here is the code is `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

        if shortcutItem.type == "Micheal-Smith.Pathfinder-Society.charLog"
        {
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let charLog = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CharacterLog") as! CharactersTableViewController
            let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

            root?.present(charLog, animated: false, completion: { 
                completionHandler(true)
            })
        }
        else if shortcutItem.type == "Micheal-Smith.Pathfinder-Society.gmTools"
        {
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let charLog = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gmTools") as! UITabBarController
            let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

            root?.present(charLog, animated: false, completion: {
                completionHandler(true)
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to handle the presentation of the VC is to embed your VC in a Navigation Controller. You would then give the NavigationController a Storyboard ID. Then you would present it to the screen. Here is an example:

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let charLog = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CharacterLog") as! UINavigationController 
        let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
root.present(charLog, animated: false, completion: { 
            completionHandler(true)
        })
```

The "CharacterLog" would be set as the NavigationController StoryBoard ID instead of the ViewController you as shown in the link below.

https://www.screencast.com/t/mcG5v5gvz

I'm going to post it in the answer as well, But here is the link to the Github tutorial I made for you to follow.

https://github.com/karpisdiem/3D-Quick-Qctions-Swift

Comment: So trying that the only thing that is missing is the back button. When I go to that ViewController either through normal navigation or through the quick touch I have no way to go back a menu.

Comment: So I made this GitHub project, I think this will help. https://github.com/karpisdiem/3D-Quick-Qctions-Swift

Comment: Awesome. This worked for the most part. I do get a funky result. So right now I have 2 shortcuts set up. The first one works beautiful. Then the second one works but I get a message in the console: Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged and when I go to the main menu my buttons are not the standard bluish color (slightly color blind). When I click the buttons on the main menu they return to the normal color. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Either way I have decided to rebuild the App from ground up. I found several inconsistencies in my naming. I have to rewrite a whole VC. It needed to be based on floats and not ints. I have to redesign my switch statements because of this, several options I needed that I didn't have. Some of the classes had CoreData and others were added later. Its a hot mess, either way I am starting fresh and going to clean up a lot. I'm bad at adding my comment lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the navigationController directly from the storyboard.

```
let charLog = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavCharacterLog") as! UINavigationController
```

Comment: That opens the app then it crashes on the loading screen gives error  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException